# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 2, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

My model is a (trained EfficientNetB0)+LSTM model and My data has two classes.

I know the same question has been asked already, but the answer did not work in my case.

This is where I create the model and try to train it. But in the model.fit section I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 2, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, 224, 224, 3)
```

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

def create_model():
    conv_base = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    conv_base.trainable = True
    
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(conv_base)
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(32))
  
    cnn = models.Model(model.input, model.output)
    
    seq_input = Input(shape=(2,224,224,3))
    
    encoded_sequence = TimeDistributed(cnn)(seq_input)
    encoded_sequence = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))(encoded_sequence)
    encoded_sequence = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))(encoded_sequence)
    out = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(encoded_sequence)
    cnn_lstm = models.Model(seq_input, out)
    cnn_lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),metrics=['acc'])
    
    if fold_count == 1:
        cnn_lstm.summary()
    return cnn_lstm
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


hist_EfficientNetB0LSTM = {}
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

fold_count=0
for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X_train,Y_train):
    fold_count = fold_count + 1
    
    x_train, x_val = np.array(X_train)[train_index], np.array(X_train)[val_index]
    y_train, y_val = np.array(Y_train)[train_index], np.array(Y_train)[val_index]
    
    y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=2)
    y_val = np_utils.to_categorical(y_val, num_classes=2)
    
    model = create_model()
    # from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
    # plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    
    print(x_train.dtype, y_train.dtype)

    x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
  

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=50, batch_size=10, validation_data = (x_val,y_val), shuffle=True)
    plot_results(history)
    hist_EfficientNetB0LSTM['fold'+str(fold_count)+'_history']= history.history
    hist_EfficientNetB0LSTM['fold'+str(fold_count)+'_results'] = calculate_test_accuracy()
    print('fold_'+str(fold_count)+' done!')
    with open(base_dir+'hist_EfficientNetB0LSTM_fold_'+str(fold_count), 'wb') as file_pi1:
        pickle.dump(hist_EfficientNetB0LSTM, file_pi1)
```

What could be the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused here about the architecture of the model. But as far as I understand, you are just trying to make your input go through CNN model and become a 1-dimensional vector, which has 32 elements in it, and want that happen at 2 timesteps using `TimeDistributed` Layer.

Whatever is the case, I think what should be done is **to change your X_train and other datasets to have a `(2, 224, 224, 3)` shape**.

For example, if you see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed link, it's assuming to have inputs `(32 video sample numbers as batch size, 10 timesteps, 224 image height, 224 image width, 3 image channel)`

Just try to check whether your inputs are well-suited for using this `TimeDistributed` layer. If your inputs don't have sequence and are just plain images, you might be trying something unachivable for `TimeDistributed` layer

Comment: Or you might change the `seq_input = Input(shape=(2,224,224,3))` line to `seq_input = Input(shape=(224,224,3))`, but I don't think that is not what you want for using `TimeDistributed` layer.